# Inverted index in a search engine

Tags: search-engine, inverted-index

I'm trying to write some code to make a small application for searching text from files.

Files should be crawled, and I need to put an inverted index to boost searches.

My problem is that I kind of have ideas about how the parser would be; I'm willing to implement the AND, NOT, OR in the query.

Whereas, I couldn't figure out how my index should be... I have never created an inverted index so if anybody could suggest a feasible way to do it, I would be very grateful. I do know in theory how it works but my problem is I absolutely have no idea how to make happen in MySql. I need to give keywords being indexed a weight too.

Comment: Do you need to do this manually, or are you able to use an existing solution such as Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple implementation.  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Inverted_Index

Answer (score 1):

Choice 1: Apache Solr/Lucene. Choice 2: mysql's full text index support.

Comment: Choice 3: MySQL or a XML stream in combination with sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/)